# Method to find 2^x quickly

Tags: c++, c

How to find 2^x quickly in C. If you guys have any idea please help.

Comment: It's called a bit-shift.

Comment: Hint, represent in binary `2^n` for a couple of small values of n and you will get the algorithm...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bitshift to the left, this multiplies numbers by 2 for every place shift, in the same way that shifting decimal numbers to the left multiplies them by 10.

Use the `<<` operator, like so:

```
int twoPowZero = 1; // any number^0 is 1
int twoPowOne  = 1 << 1; // this sets the '2' bit to '1'
int twoPowTwo  = 1 << 2;
int twoPowFive = 1 << 5;
int twoPowTen  = 1 << 10;
```

and so on until you get to `1 << 30`. If you're using a signed 32-bit integer then `1 << 31` will give you -2147483648 because of two's complement. If you want to go higher than use `long long unsigned int` or `uint64_t` (64-bit integer). Or if your platform supports it: `uint128_t`.

If you want to go even higher, you'll need to roll your own "big integer" code. Note that some platforms and compilers come with a 128-bit integer type, but runtime performance varies: they may require a processor that can perform 128-bit operations, or they might break it down into two 64-bit operations.

Comment: "1 << 31 will give you -1" Probably, but not guaranteed in either C or C++. Overflow of signed integers is undefined.

Comment: 1 << 31 is unlikely to give you -1. It will probably give you MININT (a very very big negative number). The effects of 1 << (more than 31)  in my experience can give you 0 or 1, but the actual behaviour is (IIRC) undefined, and could give you anything it feels like.

Answer (score 13):

Is it int or float? For int, use left shift. For float, pow() function

Answer (score 4):

Recall that in a binary system a bit in a position `N` represents `2^N`. Therefore, the formula for positive `int` is

```
1 << x
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
  printf ("7.0 ^ 3 = %lf\n", pow (7.0,3));
  printf ("4.73 ^ 12 = %lf\n", pow (4.73,12));
  printf ("32.01 ^ 1.54 = %lf\n", pow (32.01,1.54));
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
7.0 ^ 3 = 343.000000
4.73 ^ 12 = 125410439.217423
32.01 ^ 1.54 = 208.036691
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 #include <math.h>
 float powf(float x, float y); /* C99 */
 double pow(double x, double y);
 long double powl(long double x, long double y); /* C99 */
```

Answer (score 3):

Set a `1` in the `x`th bit position: `1 << x`.

In this case `x` should be less than the width of integer type, and `x` should be positive.